# JavaMail sometimes connects to gmail, sometimes not. Seems random

Tags: java, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail

I've been trying to use JavaMail to send emails from a program for a school project. I made it work, but now it only works from time to time. Really, it doesn't matter where I am (at school, at home, at café) it sometimes works, sometimes don't.

The error message I get is:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException:        javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
>     nested exception is:
>       java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
>       at varsling.SendEmail.sendEmail(SendEmail.java:40)

The weird thing is that I'm not changing the code in any way. Is there a problem with the JavaMail and gmail connection?

Anyways, here's my code :)

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendEmail {

public void sendEmail(String text, String to, String username, String password) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });

    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@no-spam.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject("Danger!");
        message.setText(text);

        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
} }
```

It doesn't really help to change the setFrom() to anything else, so I put it to default (what I found in the example on some website a couple of weeks ago).

Does anyone have any fixes? :S

Thanks alot!

Comment: Looks ok for me, and there is nothing that looks like depending the time of day. I would point for communication failures; when it fails try to do a `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465` and check if the server answers or if the connection is refused/timed-out.

Comment: You aren't the only one with this  issue. This happens with O365 as well but sometimes doesn't show that it's failing but the email never get's sent. If I do the same thing in Python or Powershell it NEVER fails so I'm not sure where the issue is but suspect JavaMail has some issues yet to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment above says, it sounds like a networking problem, not a JavaMail problem.  Perhaps you have a firewall or antivirus software that's interfering with your ability to connect?

You might also want to read [this JavaMail FAQ entry of common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) and clean up your code, although I doubt that it's related to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for answers. Both of you :)

I enabled the telnet client on control panel and tested what SJuan76 said: "telnet smtp.gmail.com 465" in the cmd (windows 7).

Result: "Can not establish a connection to host, on port 465: Cannot connect" - Directly translated.

Comment: I just turned off my firewall, but it didn't help. Still can't connect to smtp :S

Comment: If telnet can't connect, then you have a more basic networking problem.  Perhaps you're behind a network firewall that is refusing to let you connect?  Try "ping smtp.gmail.com" to see if there's a route to the host.